# Deleting a single SQLite row

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-delete, delete-row

I am trying to delete a single row using `onLongClick` of list item but sometime it deletes the row and sometimes doesn't. Maybe I am passing the wrong id to it I don't getting what actually problem is.

I have tried some code and I am trying from last 2 days but unable to resolve this.

Below is my code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, final long id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FavouriteListActivity.this);
        alert.setMessage("Do you want to unfavorite selected item ?");
        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.i("===========", "Position === " + position);
                Log.i("===========", "long id === " + id);
                deleteMethod(id);
                showFavouriteList();
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return true;
    }
```

And deleteMethod

```
private void deleteMethod(long Id) {
        try {
            long shId = Id + 1;
            SQLiteDatabase db = OpenHelper.getDataHelper(getApplicationContext());
            String query = "DELETE FROM " + LocalDatabase.FAVORITE_LIST.TABLE_FAVOURITE_LIST + " WHERE " + LocalDatabase.FAVORITE_LIST.FAVOURITE_LIST_ID + " = " + shId;
            Log.i("QUERY", "" + query);
            db.execSQL(query);
            db.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am not getting any error, though, but it is not deleting item from database or from listview

Comment: It's all correct, I guess you have not updated your version of app and not updated the onupdate method of ur dbhelper class, just to avoid all this just unistall the app from ur testing device and run again.

Comment: @HAXM, Thank you for quick reply.  i have tried everything so manytimes but nothing works..Even i have tried updating version, removing database and data from device every possible way...

Comment: Are you sure the exception is not being logged? Have you tried running the sql on a background thread? Are you sure the listview refresh logic is correct? is the adapter being reloaded from the db ?

Comment: Yes i am sure i am not getting any exception, but one thing i noticed is i am getting same id everytime i delete the item, may be that is the reason because it tries to delete the same item again and again which is not present in database. But i dont know why this is happening.

Comment: @HAXM, See this is what i got n logcat **DELETE FROM favourite_list WHERE id = 1** but when i checked in database after pulling it from DDMS it showing id=2. Why ??? It means it passes wrong id everytime or may be sometime

Comment: I think you are getting an ID which has nothing to do with your database elements ID. You are getting the ID of the Adapter's row, but this isn't your database element ID, until you have setted it before, have you done it?

Comment: Then surely the id ur passing is not correct, just rename the constant id as: _id instant whatever is ur current value in the constant id variable

Comment: The id ur passing is not correct it's the position of current item first make a logic to get the id of current item then use that id to delete it

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez, I think the mistake is somewhere else and somehow i am not able to catch it up..

Comment: Show us where you are setting your database elements ID to the Adapter rows

Comment: @HAXM, How do i get the id of particular position in listview. If you can help then it would be easier to me to overcome this problem.

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez, Check my edit...

Comment: U r able to access the row at a position Right?, So u can see all variables value at that same position try to get value of _id and use this to delete that row.

Comment: @HAXM, The scenario is when i enter 2 row in favorite list and delete the second and first then no problem, but if i delete the first row and then if i try to delete the second it wont delete instead it passing the same ID...

Comment: Cause ur passing the position u have to pass I'd not position, for first time u pass the position then it was present in database, but now u try to delete a variable on same position having different id , it will not work because it's position is not present in data base as this was used to delete previous one, u just first get the id then use to delete that row as I mentioned earlier

Comment: why do you use `execSQL` and `rawQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a id variable in your model class and generate getter and setter for that:

```
public static final String PRIMARY_ID="_id";
```

Now set the primeary_id to model from the cursor:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                model = new FavouriteListVo(lngID, strName);
                  model.setStrName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocalDatabase.FAVORITE_LIST.FAVOURITE_LIST_NAME)));
model.setPrimId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocalDatabase.FAVORITE_LIST.PRIMARY_ID)));
                arrayListFav.add(model);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

Now for deleting that row use this primary key:

```
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String id=model.getPrimId();
            deleteMethod(id);
            showFavouriteList();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
```

The delete function is exactlu same as yours, as I mentioned in comment that the problem is with id not your delete function:

```
private void deleteMethod(long Id) {
    try {
        long shId = Id + 1;
        SQLiteDatabase db = OpenHelper.getDataHelper(getApplicationContext());
        String query = "DELETE FROM " + LocalDatabase.FAVORITE_LIST.TABLE_FAVOURITE_LIST + " WHERE " + LocalDatabase.FAVORITE_LIST.FAVOURITE_LIST_ID + " = " + shId;
        Log.i("QUERY", "" + query);
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```